# ionic2 data retrieving from a function to html page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have this code and I need the `datee1` value in my HTML page, how can I do this?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-edcfromlmp',
  templateUrl: 'edcfromlmp.html'
})
export class EdcfromlmpPage {

    myDate: String = new Date().toISOString();

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {}

    datechange(datee) {
        datee = new Date(datee);
        var datee1 = datee.setDate(datee.getDate() + 280);
        datee1 = new Date(datee1);
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad EdcfromlmpPage');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign it to a publicly accessible variable (this.variableName)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-edcfromlmp',
  templateUrl: 'edcfromlmp.html'
})
export class EdcfromlmpPage {
    htmlDate: any; //create a variable
    myDate: String = new Date().toISOString();

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {}

    datechange(datee) {
        datee = new Date(datee);
        var datee1 = datee.setDate(datee.getDate() + 280);
        datee1 = new Date(datee1);
        this.htmlDate = datee1; // assign it
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad EdcfromlmpPage');
    }
}
```

then in your HTML just call

```
<p>{{htmlDate}}</p> <!-- will print [Object object] probably -->
<p>{{htmlDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</p> <!-- will print 26/01/2017 -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Public variables declared in a component class are available to that component's template. You can just make a public variable called `datee1` in the class like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-edcfromlmp',
  templateUrl: 'edcfromlmp.html'
})
export class EdcfromlmpPage {

    datee1: Date
    myDate: String = new Date().toISOString();

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {}

    datechange(datee) {
        datee = new Date(datee);
        var tempDate = datee.setDate(datee.getDate() + 280);
        this.datee1 = new Date(tempDate);
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad EdcfromlmpPage');
    }
}
```

Then you can just refer to `datee1` in your `edcfromlmp.html` HTML template page. For example you can do `<h1>{{datee1}}</h1>` to print the `datee1` variable as an `h1` header. Be aware that variables from component classes are only scoped to that components template page.